# How would I ensure that only authorised users are able to access this class based view

Tags: python, django, authorization

I have a risk entry view that only project managers are able to access and no other user group how would I ensure that only this user group is able to access this view?

## Risk page class-based view

```
@method_decorator(decorators, name='dispatch')
class Risk_entry_page(View):

    template_name = 'risk/riskEntry.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargds):
        return render(request, self.template_name)
```

## Risk Urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Solution_area_home_page.as_view(), name='risks-home-page'),
    path('risk/', views.Risk_entry_page.as_view(), name='risk-entry-page'),
    path('assumption/', views.Assumption_entry_page.as_view(), name='assumption-entry-page'),
    path('issue/', views.Issue_entry_page.as_view(), name='issue-entry-page'),
    path('dependency/', views.Dependency_entry_page.as_view(), name='dependency-entry-page'),
    path('logout/', views.Logout.as_view(), name='logout-view'),
]
```

Comment: you would use permissions ....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give access to ***Authorized*** user only then you can introduce Permission in your project, so that user with certain permission can be accesible to your *Risk_entry_page* class
https://django-permission.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

If You want only ***login*** user can access, you *Risk_entry_page* class then use Login Required mixin.

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

@method_decorator(decorators, name='dispatch')
class Risk_entry_page(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    template_name = 'risk/riskEntry.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargds):
        return render(request, self.template_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin). You probably however want to limit the view to users with a given (set of) permission(s) with the [**`PermissionRequiredMixin`** mixin <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-permissionrequiredmixin-mixin):

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class MyView(PermissionRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    permission_required = 'some_app.some_permssion'
    template_name = 'risk/riskEntry.html'
```